# Sqoop2: setting table.sql in connectorForm (using free from query) returns 'unacceptable' status on createJob()

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, sqoop

Am referring to this guide for writing my Sqoop2 client program:
http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.2/ClientAPI.html

The example shows just setting the column names in table.columns property, it works fine but imports all the records in the table.  I need to import only a set of records based on a simple where-clause sql.  I tried setting table.sql property but it always return 'unacceptable' status on invoking SqoopClient.createJob(newJob).  Anyone has run import successfully using free form query in Sqoop2 (CDH4.4.0)?

```
connectorForm.getStringInput("table.sql").setValue("select id,value from tableName where ${CONDITIONS} and groupid=123");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the overall status returned by the SqoopClient.createJob(), the given MJob object will be altered with status messages. You can get precise error messages of what is wrong with your job via iterating over the forms and inputs and calling method [getValidationMessage()](https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/sqoop2/common/src/main/java/org/apache/sqoop/model/MValidatedElement.java#L86).

Comment: Thanks Jarek.  When specifying sql, schema and table name 'should NOT' be given.  I had fed all three into the job and hence the issue. After removing schema and table name, it worked!